# Loading a ResourceDictionary with siteoforigin

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible when loading a `ResourceDictionary` from the output folder that the keys are available at design time?
If I load a `ResourceDictionary` like this, the designer doens't know about its keys.

In `App.xaml` I have the following code:

```
 <ResourceDictionary
     Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Themes/Dark/Dark.xaml" />
```

I tried loading the `ResourceDictionary` from the output folder and the keys are not available at design time.

Comment: Why are you using site of origin rather than just Source="/Resources/Themes/Dark/Dark.xaml" set the xaml file properties as content copy if newer.

Comment: Because the xaml files are from a different styling Project, and copied to the output folder in the main Project. they are set to Content and Copy Always in the styling Project. I tried setting them to Build Action: Page and Copy Always but that doesn't work. I need the xaml files to be loaded in the main Project at Design Time, but I cannot do this loading the xaml Resources from the output folder.

Comment: There's design time resources https://github.com/jbe2277/waf/wiki/WPF-Design-Time-Support-(Part-2)